# background image vanishes on zoom out

Tags: css

. . . . I have a very simple html and css

```
<style media="all" type="text/css">
#header-bg
{   
    background-image:url(header_bg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:496px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
</style>
<div id="header-bg"></div>
```

The background image vanishes on zoom out. The image size is 1 x 496!
[this is the background image used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i4cL.png)

Any idea what exactly is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes browsers do weird stuff with zooming and they all do it a little different. Try to make the image 2 pixels wide and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you trying to achieve. Try **background-size: cover**.